# sasl/saslwrapper.h:22:23: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, sasl

I have OS

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
```

and python

```
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Tried to install lib sasl

sudo pip install sasl

```
Collecting sasl
  Downloading http://repo.com/api/pypi/pypi/packages/8e/2c/45dae93d666aea8492678499e0999269b4e55f1829b1e4de5b8204706ad9/sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz
Collecting six (from sasl)
  Downloading http://repo.com/api/pypi/pypi/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, sasl

    building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isasl -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl/saslwrapper.o
    In file included from sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:254:0:
    sasl/saslwrapper.h:22:23: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
     #include <sasl/sasl.h>
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Ym7ZOA/sasl/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_8ahws-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Ym7ZOA/sasl/
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: your librarries in `/tmp/` folder ?

Comment: if I right understood pip installer copy librarries into /tmp/ in process installing worked

Comment: dont use PIP for this, download this file and install manually!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/1256), it seems that you need the `libsasl2`.

You can install libsasl2 by using the command :-

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

Answer (score 45):

if you are on AWS EC2/EMR or CentOS, `sudo yum install cyrus-sasl-devel`

Comment: Worked for me on Amazon Linux 1 on an AWS EC2-Instance when I was trying to run `sudo -E pip-3.6 install apache-airflow[all]` :) thanks!

Comment: Worked for my Using AWS EMR 6.3! Thanks!