# Unable to build docker image with sasl python module

Tags: python, macos, docker, pip

I am trying to build a docker image containing Python 2 on my mac (High Sierra). Here is the docker file. (build command: `docker build -t integration_test .`)

```
FROM python:2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "nosetests" ]
```

Here are the contents of the `requirements.txt`

```
nose
pyhive
thrift
sasl
thrift_sasl
python-dateutil
future
six>=1.7.2
```

When I try to build the docker image, I get the following error.

```
Failed building wheel for sasl
  Running setup.py clean for sasl
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thrift-sasl: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thrift-sasl: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c8/3a/34/1d82df3d652788fc211c245d51dde857a58e603695ea41d93d
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for future: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for future: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/bf/c9/a3/c538d90ef17cf7823fa51fc701a7a7a910a80f6a405bf15b1a
Successfully built pyhive thrift thrift-sasl future
Failed to build sasl
Installing collected packages: nose, future, six, python-dateutil, pyhive, thrift, sasl, thrift-sasl
  Running setup.py install for sasl: started
    Running setup.py install for sasl: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-Dd4Z7v/sasl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-_rw4YI/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    copying sasl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to sasl.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing sasl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    running build_ext
    building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Isasl -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl/saslwrapper.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:254:0:
    sasl/saslwrapper.h:22:23: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
     #include <sasl/sasl.h>
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-Dd4Z7v/sasl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-_rw4YI/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Dd4Z7v/sasl/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have seen a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562383/sasl-saslwrapper-h2223-fatal-error-sasl-sasl-h-no-such-file-or-directory) It talks about installing the dependent library on host OS. I wanted to know how this can be done on docker image/container.

Has anyone faced this problem before? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sasl/saslwrapper.h:22:23: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562383/sasl-saslwrapper-h2223-fatal-error-sasl-sasl-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @DavidMaze I saw this question. It is related to a host and not a docker. I don't know to install a SO file in a docker and that's why I titled this question with docker

Comment: Add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libsasl2-dev` in your Dockerfile before `pip install`

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. Please add this as an answer. You should get a credit to this as an accepted answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install `libsasl2-dev` to your Docker image.

In its simplest form, add the following line to your Dockerfile before `pip install`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

Comment: I am trying to build the image with python 3.9 with sasl. Before installing sasl I am trying to install libsasl2-dev as well. But its giving me same error. Its not really working for py 3.9.*
However Its working for python 3.8.12

Answer (score 1):

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gcc g++ libsasl2-dev -y`
if anyone's build fail due to GCC missing.
Airflow is using a slim python image without gcc.